# Java String split Inside brackets

Tags: java, regex, string, split

`String s = "Length(1-2), Width(3-4), Height(5-6)"`

I need to get values only inside brackets i.e -

```
[1-2, 3-4, 5-6]
```

When I use `s.split("\\((.*?)\\)")`, I get values ​​outside my parentheses, but I need inside. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use `split`. Use `(?<=\()[^)]*(?=\))` regex and a `while` loop using `matcher.find()`

Comment: You can match them with your regex.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s = "Length(1-2), Width(3-4), Height(5-6)";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\((.*?)\\)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);

while(m.find()) {
  System.out.println(m.group(1));
}
```